# Differential manifold connection with different notation

Tags: analysis, smooth-manifolds, differential, submanifold

We aim to prove that the set
{V(n, 2) = {(a, b) \in R^n \times R^n : |a|^2 = |b|^2 = 1 \text{ and } <a,b> = 0}
is a smooth (2n-3)-submanifold of R^n \times R^n. 
This will be demonstrated by considering the function f :R^n \times R^n \rightarrow R^3 given by
f(a, b) = (|a|^2, |b|^2, <a,b>)
and showing that the derivative $Df(a, b)$ is a surjective linear transformation for all (a, b) $\in$ V(n, 2). 
Should I use the implicit function theorem to prove the first one with derivative is the surjective linear mapping to R^3? and I dont know how to proof second part. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you written down the derivative matrix explicitly? What do you notice about its row vectors? P.S. I do not understand your title.